# On Change of Data Type of a Property update all the local variables Method signatures Which use the property

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I have a class say Base Which contains a Property say Id

```
public abstract class Base
{
    public abstract int Id { get; }
}
```

This abstract class has many concrete derived classes. e.g;

```
public class Concrete: Base
{
    public override int Id
    {
        get { return importChangekeyLogId; }
    }
}
```

Also In my code solution, there are places where this Property Value is stored in a local variable or passed as a parameter to the method. Check below example where local variable id stores property value and `SampleChild2` method accepts int which is the value of Property Id.

```
public int Sample1(Concrete obj)
{
    int id = obj.Id;
    SmapleChild2(obj.Id);
    return id;
}

public void SmapleChild2(int id)
{
}
```

**Requirement**: The above property is just an example we have many such kinds of properties and the estimated time if done manually is 38 days. Therefore, I want to write a utility using Roslyn Through which I can change the data type of Properties to long and also I could find all the references of Properties and update the local variable data types and method signatures. So the final code should be like

```
public abstract class Base
{
    public abstract long Id { get; }       
}

public class Concrete: Base
{
    public override long Id
    {
        get { return importChangekeyLogId; }
    }
}

public long Sample1(Concrete obj)
{
    long id = obj.Id;
    SmapleChild2(obj.Id);
    return id;
}

public void SmapleChild2(long id)
{
}
```

**Code done till now**: I am able to change the abstract class property data type to long using code like below

```
public override SyntaxNode VisitPropertyDeclaration(PropertyDeclarationSyntax node)
{
    PredefinedTypeSyntax _longType = SyntaxFactory.PredefinedType(SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.LongKeyword)).WithTrailingTrivia(SyntaxFactory.SyntaxTrivia(SyntaxKind.WhitespaceTrivia, " "));

    if (node.Type.ToString() == "int")
    {
        var propertyName = node.Identifier.ValueText;
        if (propertyName == "Id")
        {
            return node.ReplaceNode(node.Type, _longType);
        }   
    }

    return node;
}
```

I am able to find all the references where the property is being used from the below code. But I am not able to find a way to update the local variable's data type and method signatures which deal with the property value.

```
if (propertyName == "Id")
{
    var propertySymbol = (IPropertySymbol)_semanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(node);
    var references = SymbolFinder.FindReferencesAsync(propertySymbol, this._solution).Result;
}
```

Comment: This could easily be done within Visual Studio or with extensions like [Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), [Code Maid](http://www.codemaid.net/) or any good C# IDE with a replace/rename command if you have access to the source code